# SWIG error for boost::posix_time::ptime conversion

Tags: swig

I am warping a very simple C++ class by using SWIG.
The boost ptime is used in that C++ class.

When I try to execute command

```
swig -c++ -python example.i
```

There is an error:

```
example.h:7: Warning 315: Nothing known about 'boost::posix_time::ptime'.
example.h:7: Warning 315: Nothing known about 'boost::posix_time::ptime'.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

The example.i file is:

```
//File: example.i
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp>
#include "example.h"
%}

// for std:string
%include "std_string.i"

// for vector
%include "std_vector.i"

%include stl.i
%include "example.h"
```

The example.h file is:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp>

using std::string;
using boost::posix_time::ptime;

class Example{
    public:
    Example(string name, ptime timestamp){
      // doSomething...
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by friend Mike and me.

The correct interface file is as following (without mentioning boost header):

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"
```

The swig execution command is (OSX):

```
swig -c++ -python example.i 
g++ -O2  -fPIC -c example.h -std=c++11
g++ -O2  -fPIC -c example_wrap.cxx -I/Library/anaconda2/include/python2.7
g++ -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -o _example.so *.o
```

The swig execution command is (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
swig -c++ -python example.i 
g++ -O2  -fPIC -c example.h -std=c++11
g++ -O2  -fPIC -c example_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared -o _example.so *.o
```

Only change the last line.